# Short title in header but not ToC for document class book

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to have a short title of chapters and sections in my headers, but in the ToC there should appear the long title.

I am using the `book` document class, and package `fancyhdr`. 
`\section[short title]{long title}` gives me the headers I want, but then the short title is also placed in the ToC.

This didn't work out in my case: [Short title that is not displayed in the ToC {hyperref}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/short-title-that-is-not-displayed-in-the-toc-hyperref)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you  use package `titlesec`, this is done through  the `[toctitles]` option.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see your answer at first, but this is actually the fastest solution!

Answer (score 2):

The following updates the way the marks are used when setting the chapter and sectional titles within the `book` class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\makeatletter

% Update how \chapter is added to the ToC/header
\let\oldchaptermark\chaptermark
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\oldchaptermark{\@chaptermark}}% Used stored chapter mark
\let\old@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \def\@chaptermark{#1}% Store chapter mark
  \old@chapter[#2]{#2}%
}

% Update how \section and \subsection is added to the ToC/header
\let\oldsectionmark\sectionmark
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\oldsectionmark{\@sectionmark}}% Used stored section mark
\let\oldsubsectionmark\subsectionmark
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\oldsubsectionmark{\@subsectionmark}}% Used stored subsection mark
\let\old@sect\@sect
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \@namedef{@#1mark}{#7}% Store sectional mark
  \old@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#8]{#8}% 
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy % Just for this example
\chapter[Chapter short title]{Chapter long title}
\lipsum[1-50]

\section[Section short title]{Section long title}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but... then it doesn't know the command \section any more. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: @Anja: In my example there is no problem. Can you elaborate on what packages you use? Perhaps start by taking my example and adding packages you use until something goes wrong. This way you can identify the conflicting package(s). Give some feedback on your findings.

Comment: Actually several of the packages were causing problems, so in my case the solution suggested by Peter Wilson was just faster to get it to run. Thank you still.

Answer (score 1):

If you would care to change to the `memoir` class (which encompasses the `book` class and an equivalent of the `fancyhdr` package) then:

```
\chapter[<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}
\section[<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}
```

puts `<toc-title>` in the ToC, `<head-title>` in the header and `<title>` in the body of the document. SimIlarly the same constructs are available for `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, with memoir class I get some new problems: \onehalfspacing doesn't work any longer and I can not make titlepages with \begin{titlepage}. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Anja Try `\OnehalfSpacing` and the `titllingpage` environment. (No need for any packages for these).